# Sorting table fetch using 2 order by clase in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I want to sort data fetched from the database by the number of votes My MySql code ends with ORDER BY number_of_votes DESC. But if there's a tie in the result, I want to break it by favoring the entry that was submitted first, so how can I do this with MySql or do I need php intervention to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just add another clause:

```
ORDER BY number_of_votes DESC, submitted_at DESC
```

In case you are wondering, this is standard SQL syntax, so it is database agnostic.

Comment: sure, but need to wait 5 minutes.. sorry im a novice to this site